# drop dupliactes but keep records based on a condtion

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, join, duplicates

I have two tables with same columns, and I concatenated them vertically. I want to remove duplicates based on `col1` but keep records that have latest `time_stamp`

Comment: Could you please post samples of input and expected output in your question and let us know then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sort the dataframe on the value of time stamp descending and the default behaviour of the pandas drop_duplicates method will keep the latest